# Renderer2.setProperty() doesn't update the value

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to update the value using the rendered.setproperty() where value is updating the second time on listen  event

these are the value that I am sending for the first time as empty in some widget

```html
<ols-giftcard-payment-widget site-id="dddd" customer-last-name="" jwt-token="abcd"></ols-giftcard-payment-widget>
```

here I want to update the customer-last-name as a dynamic value

```js
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
  createRecaptchaContainer() {
    const recaptchaContainer = this.renderer.createElement(
      'ols-giftcard-payment-widget'
    );
    this.renderer.setProperty(recaptchaContainer, 'siteId', '56711');
    this.renderer.setProperty(
      recaptchaContainer,
      'jwtToken',
      'abcd'
    );
    let cardClickEvent = this.renderer.listen(
      recaptchaContainer,
      'addCard',
      (evt) => {
        this.renderer.setProperty(
          recaptchaContainer,
          'customerLastName',
          'anonymousLastName'
        );
        this.renderer.appendChild(
          document.getElementById('payment-widget'),
          recaptchaContainer
        );

        return recaptchaContainer;

        debugger;
      }
    );
    this.renderer.appendChild(
      document.getElementById('payment-widget'),
      recaptchaContainer
    );

    return recaptchaContainer;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createRecaptchaContainer();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="payment-widget"></div>
```

Here I am trying to add the customerLastname in this setProperty
this.renderer.setProperty(
recaptchaContainer,
'customerLastName',
'anonymousLastName'
);
it is updating on the second click, not on the first click

please help me to find here where I am wrong in the implementation

Answer (score 0):

Your error message was `Please provide the last name`. Apparently `recaptchaContainer` needs a name to work.

When you click "Add card" for the first time `customerLastName` is empty. Look it up on localStorage under key `cardDetails`. `anonymousLastName` is added with click listener event from the component **after** data has been sent, that's why it works second time around.

```
{
  "siteId": "56711",
  "customerNumber": "",
  "customerFirstName": "",
  "customerLastName": "anonymousLastName",
  "customerSession": "",
  "companyId": "",
  "primaryColor": "#2196F3"
}
```

To fix this, we could also setProperty for `customerLastName` outside of the event listener, so that `customerLastName` would be populated on first click. Either that or put something in `customer-last-name=""`.

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<div id="payment-widget" (click)="setUsername('123')"></div>
<br>
<input [(ngModel)]="username" (input)="onChange()" #ctrl="ngModel" required>

<p>Value: {{ username }}</p>
<p>Valid: {{ ctrl.valid }}</p>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  show: boolean = false;
  jwtToknVal = of();
  title = 'angular';
  username: string;
  recaptchaContainer: any;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
  createRecaptchaContainer() {
    this.recaptchaContainer = this.renderer.createElement(
      'ols-giftcard-payment-widget'
    );
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.recaptchaContainer, 'siteId', '56711');
    this.renderer.setProperty(
      this.recaptchaContainer,
      'jwtToken',
      'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vMXJ5ZzMwZjZnay5leGVjdXRlLWFwaS51cy13ZXN0LTIuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbS9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGUiLCJzY29wZSI6InNlbGYiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTkxMTIxMjcsImV4cCI6MTcxOTE5ODUyNywicm9sZXMiOlsiY29tbXVuaXR5X2FwcGxpY2F0aW9uX2FjY2Vzc3wxMTE4N3wxIl0sInVzZXIiOnsiaWQiOiIyNTc1NyIsIm5hbWUiOiJTaG9ydGN1dHMiLCJzdXJuYW1lIjoiUFBGIiwiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSI6IlNob3J0Y3V0cyIsImRpc3BsYXlfbmFtZSI6IlNob3J0Y3V0cyBQUEYiLCJlbWFpbCI6InNob3J0Y3V0c0BzaG9ydGN1dHNzb2Z0d2FyZWRldi5jb20ifX0.vll2mLmdtBuuz0mnlENEAs1xT0In0NmYKBWD67VfYdw'
    );
    this.renderer.appendChild(
      document.getElementById('payment-widget'),
      this.recaptchaContainer
    );

    this.renderer.setProperty(
      this.recaptchaContainer,
      'customerLastName',
      this.username
    );
    this.renderer.listen(this.recaptchaContainer, 'addCard', (evt) => {
      console.log(this.recaptchaContainer, evt);
      this.renderer.setProperty(
        this.recaptchaContainer,
        'customerLastName',
        this.username
      );
      return this.recaptchaContainer;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createRecaptchaContainer();
  }

  onChange() {
    console.log(this.username);
  }

  setUsername(name: string) {
    this.renderer.setProperty(
      this.recaptchaContainer,
      'customerLastName',
      name
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkua7n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: is it not possible if I leave customer last name as empty before listen  event and then assign a value on the button click because I have the same requirement for others too need to assign value after listen event

Comment: The solution you mentied i tried it already its working but I need a value to be assigned after listen event only

Comment: I see. I have updated my version to include input field where you can send the username. The problem is that the click event listener happens `after` the the token and username is sent. Your appending it after it's been sent that's why it works the second time around. I suggest using some other way (like input) or use additional `(click)` event `<div id="payment-widget" (click)="setUsername('123')"></div>`. Anyway, I updated my code.

Comment: Sorry its not working.